# Performance metrics calculation for SQL queries

Tags: mysql, performance, jdbc, time, cpu-usage

I have two databases A and B on **MySQL server**.

A is the original database and B is derived from A changing the format of some tables. So for each table_A in db A there's a respective table table_B in db B and for each row in table_A there is a respective row in table_B representing the exact same table entry, in a different format.

I'm pretty sure that explaining this "*format difference*" between A and B is irrelevant of what I'm going to ask.

I use **Java**, **JDBC** actually, to interface with MySQL server.

I have a number of "SELECT" queries for db A and the equivalent queries for db B. I want to execute them repeatedly and calculate some metrics, like so:

```
execute SELECT query on db A and calculate metrics;
execute equivalent SELECT query on db B and calculate metrics;
UPDATE data stored in db A and db B by a percentage 
loop
```

The final goal is to compare the performance of the "same" queries on the two twin dbs, to see what effect the "*format difference*" has in query performance.

My questions:

- How can I calculate CPU time of the query execution? Currently what I do is:

  `long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);
  long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;`

  Is this accurate?
- How can I calculate other metrics such as memory usage, cache usage, disk reads, disk writes, buffer gets
- Could anyone suggest any other metrics to compare the performance of the "same" queries on the two databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of metrics you cannot get.  But here is a set I like to get:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...; -- or whatever query
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

The last command might give something like

```
mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 1     |
| Handler_read_key           | 1     |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 5484  |  -- rows in the table; so it did a table scan
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 7     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 14    |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 13    |  -- wrote to a tmp table 13 rows after a GROUP BY
+----------------------------+-------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Caching comes and goes, so timings can vary even by a factor of 10.  Handlers, on the other hand, are very consistent.  They give me insight into what is happening.

If you are running through JDBC, run the FLUSH like you would a non-SELECT; run the SHOW like a SELECT that gives you 2 columns.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm definitely going to check this stuff out! (It seems I need some more reputation to upvote you, sorry!)